# how to retrieve the data said by a user from an intent in google assistant?

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, jovo-framework

I am currently using jovo framework and writing my code with nodeJs .
my project goes like this :

> Hello! What's your name?
>
> salma
>
> Hello  Salma, nice to meet you! what do you want me to do for you?
>
> play a better radio
>
> Do you want me to play the radio called A Better Radio ?

the name of the radio "a better radio" is in the json file of the intent so
everything works fine in there. But if i say  for example "play a bet ray " the value of the radio.value becomes undefined. I want to retrieve the data said by the user "play a bet ray " so that i can analyse it .

so how can i  retrieve the data said by a user from an intent?

the json looks like this :

```
{
    "responseId": "552fd979-bf0f-4f6c-9ddd-39180824c26d",
    "queryResult": {
            "queryText": "GOOGLE_ASSISTANT_WELCOME",
            "parameters": {},
            "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
            "fulfillmentMessages": [
                    {
                            "text": {
                                    "text": [
                                            ""
                                    ]
                            }
                    }
            ],
            "outputContexts": [
                    {
                            "name": "projects/trythis-807dd/agent/sessions/1530712293227/contexts/google_assistant_welcome"
                    },
                    {
                            "name": "projects/trythis-807dd/agent/sessions/1530712293227/contexts/actions_capability_screen_output"
                    },
                    {
                            "name": "projects/trythis-807dd/agent/sessions/1530712293227/contexts/actions_capability_audio_output"
                    },
                    {
                            "name": "projects/trythis-807dd/agent/sessions/1530712293227/contexts/google_assistant_input_type_keyboard"
                    },
                    {



{
    "fulfillmentText": "<speak>Hello! What's your name?</speak>",
    "payload": {
            "google": {
                    "expectUserResponse": true,
                    "richResponse": {
                            "items": [
                                    {
                                            "simpleResponse": {
                                                    "ssml": "<speak>Hello! What's your name?</speak>"
                                            }
                                    }
                            ]
                    },
                    "noInputPrompts": [
                            {
                                    "ssml": "<speak>Please tell me your name.</speak>"
                            }
                    ]
            }
    },

{
    "responseId": "8d031a0f-9692-4e8d-a172-d7dad9c7511b",
    "queryResult": {
            "queryText": "my name is salma",
            "parameters": {
                    "name": "Salma"
            },
            "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
            "fulfillmentMessages": [
                    {
                            "text": {
                                    "text": [
                                            ""
                                    ]
                            }
                    }
            ],
            "outputContexts": [
                    {
                            "name": "projects/trythis-807dd/agent/sessions/1530712293227/contexts/actions_capability_screen_output",
                            "parameters": {
                                    "name.original": "salma",
                                    "name": "Salma"
                            }
                    },


{
    "fulfillmentText": "<speak>Hello  Salma, nice to meet you! what do you want me to do for you?</speak>",
    "payload": {
            "google": {
                    "expectUserResponse": true,
                    "richResponse": {
                            "items": [
                                    {
                                            "simpleResponse": {
                                                    "ssml": "<speak>Hello  Salma, nice to meet you! what do you want me to do for you?</speak>"
                                            }
                                    }
                            ]
                    },
                    "noInputPrompts": [
                            {
                                    "ssml": "<speak>Hey , Salma,  What can i do ?</speak>"
                            }
                    ]
            }
    },


{
    "fulfillmentText": "<speak>Hello  Salma, nice to meet you! what do you want me to do for you?</speak>",
    "payload": {
            "google": {
                    "expectUserResponse": true,
                    "richResponse": {
                            "items": [
                                    {
                                            "simpleResponse": {
                                                    "ssml": "<speak>Hello  Salma, nice to meet you! what do you want me to do for you?</speak>"
                                            }
                                    }
                            ]
                    },
                    "noInputPrompts": [
                            {
                                    "ssml": "<speak>Hey , Salma,  What can i do ?</speak>"
                            }
                    ]
            }
    },


 "fulfillmentText": "<speak>Do you want me to play the radio called A Better Radio ?</speak>",
```

i have tried :

```
let inputs = this.getInputs();

let inputs = this.user().getPrevSpeech(0);

let inputs =this.getSpeechText();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the raw text of a Google Action request with `this.$googleAction.getRawText()`.

Edit: The previous answer (`this.googleAction().getRawText()`) was for Jovo Framework version < 2.

Answer (score 1):

The preferred way of extracting information from user's speech/text is Dialogflow's entities. You can find a getting started guide for entities here: https://dialogflow.com/docs/getting-started/extract-entities

Answer (score -1):

Ok, firstly, I need to know whether you are doing this on dialogflow or for alexa (assuming its one or the other because Jovo tutorials are for those 2.

You've put dialogflow in the tag, so I'm assuming that is what you're working with.

I'm guessing you've created a parameter called radio with entity sys.any . If not then create a paramter called radio with entity sys.any; then have 5-6 training phrases(only for testing, if you implement you need a lot more) and make sure you highlight which part of it is actually the radio. This is how  you're supposed to retrieve data.

If you want to retrieve everything the user says, which is not generally good practice (unless you're testing or need everything that is said). Then just make a few training phrases with everything highlighted and with entity sys.any .

I might not understand the problem completely, I did use Jovo for a while but now I use fulfilment with firebase because its a little clearer. If so, just clarify what you think I've misunderstood.

**Also, you can get invited to the official Jovo slack:**

https://www.jovo.tech/community

The devs of Jovo are on there so they will probably be able to help you out with any issues you have.

Comment: i tried this commend :
let input = this.googleAction().getRequest();
the output :

------> let input = this.googleAction.getRequest : {"responseId":"99b75b33-6af1-4980-a857-0df07a26f716","queryResult":{"queryText":"play a better radio","
parameters":{"radioNameThree":"A Better Radio"},"allRequiredParamsPresent":true,"fulfillmentMessages":[{"text":{"text":[""]}}],"outputContexts":[{"name":"
projects/trythis-807dd/agent/sessions/1530778311493/contexts/actions_capability_screen_output","parameters":{"radioNameThree":"A Better Radio" ,"radioNameT
hree.original":"a better radio"}} ...

Comment: so this was what i was looking for :
let inputs = this.googleAction().getRequest().queryResult.queryText;
output : ------> let inputs = this.googleAction.getRequest.queryResult.queryText : play a better radio